# Rellena input email y contraseña por defecto en HTML5

Tags: html5, email, entrada, contraseña

```html
  <form id="login" method="post" action="login.php"><br>
  Email: <br>
  <input type="email" name="mail" placeholder="First name"><br>
  Contraseña: <br>
  <input type="password" name="contra" placeholder="Last name"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

yo lo que quiero es que tanto email y contraseña no se muestren en el formulario aunque el usuario haya decidido guardarlo. Es decir resetear siempre y no se coomo hacerlo. Tengo esto:

---

la verdad que con lo único que he podido ha sido con este atributo y propiedad.
autocomplete="new-password"

Comment: qué quieres resetear, no es muy entendible tu pregunta.

Puedes estructurarla mejor.

Comment: No hay nada que puedas hacer si usas input password / mail. Aunque borres, el chrome, restaurara los datos guardados.
La única solución es crear tus propios input con javascript y keypress.
Un tema difícil de resumir.

Answer (score 1):

Con [`autocomple="off"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/desactivar_autocompletado_formulario) debería no auto completar el `input`.

```html
<form id="login" method="post" action="login.php"><br>
  Email: <br>
  <input type="email" name="mail" placeholder="First name" autocomplete="off">
  <br>
  Contraseña: <br>
  <input type="password" name="contra" placeholder="Last name" autocomplete="off"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

---

También encontré esto de [Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill) que habla exactamente de lo mismo.

Comment: Gracias tio. Voy a probar...

Comment: lo he probado y no va

Answer (score 0):

No se si sea lo mejor pero podrias intentar con JQuery para que siempre que entre al ejecutarse le des el valor vacio.

```
$("#mail").val('');
$("#contra").val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
  <form id="login" method="post" action="login.php"><br>
  Email: <br>
  <input type="email" name="mail" style="display:none"><br>
  <input type="email" name="mail" placeholder="First name"><br>
  Contraseña: <br>
  <input type="password" name="contra" style="display:none"><br>
  <input type="password" name="contra" placeholder="Last name"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Para deshabilitar en Chrome el autofill debes crear campos de tipo idénticos pero ocultos.